# What is the way for direct assignment?

Tags: c#

What is the way to add items to list when i have class setup

```
class person
    {
        string name;
        List<RecipeList> rcp = new List<RecipeList>();
        public List<RecipeList> RList
        {
            get { return rcp; }
            set { rcp = value; }
        }
        public string Name
        {
            get{return name;}
            set {name=value;}
        }
    }



   class RecipeList
    {
        string nameofrec;
        public string NameofRecipe
        {
            get { return nameofrec; }
            set { nameofrec = value; }
        }
    }
```

**following declaration not working**

```
person[] prn = new person[]

 { new person { Name = "Robert",
    RList=new List<RecipeList>().AddRange("Coak","Pizza")},

 new person { Name = "Rahim",
              RList =new List<RecipeList>().AddRange("Coak","OnionBread")}
 };
```

Answer (score 3):

The `RList` isn't a list of `string`s - you need to use `ReceipeList` objects, like below; note I'm using the fact that the list (`rcp`) has a field-initializer (you could actually remove the `set` and it would still work, as long as you aren't using `XmlSerializer`):

```
person[] prn = new person[]
{
    new person { Name = "Robert", RList = {
      new RecipeList { NameofRecipe = "Coak" },
      new RecipeList { NameofRecipe = "Pizza" }
    } },
    new person { Name = "Rahim", RList = {
      new RecipeList { NameofRecipe = "Coak" },
      new RecipeList { NameofRecipe = "OnionBread" }
    } },
};
```

Note that you could simplify this with a few bespoke constructors...

Comment: Well, it won't compile... what more do you need?

Comment: little bit of your brain :)   you mean to say if i remove the set during Serialization i will face problem am i right ?

Comment: spell error in my Receipe instead Recipe ( somebody pointed it),so please correct it in your answer too .

Comment: re serialization - yes, `XmlSerializer` will only serialize list properties that have a get+set, but other serializers (`BinaryFormatter`,`DataContractSerializer`,protobuf-net, etc) aren't so fussy.